# System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: 'SQL logic error near "Transaction": syntax error'

Tags: c#, sqlite

I keep getting this error every time I try to add something into the database. I am trying to add something into a database that's already in the executable.

This is how I am trying to add it:

```
public class DBAccess
{
    public static void AddTransaction(Transaction transaction)
    {
        using IDbConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnection());
        dbConnection.Execute("INSERT INTO Transaction (Category, Name, Type, Date, Amount, Method, Description, Recurring" +
            ") VALUES (@Category, @Name, @Type, @Date, @Amount, @Method, @Description, @Recurring)", transaction);
    }

    public static string LoadConnection(string conn = "Connection")
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[conn].ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

This is the model:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public int TransactionID { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public string Method { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Recurring { get; set; }
}
```

This is what I am trying to add:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Transaction transaction = new Transaction();

        Console.WriteLine("Category: ");
        transaction.Category = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Name: ");
        transaction.Name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Type: ");
        transaction.Type = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Date: ");
        transaction.Date = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Amount: ");
        bool isAmountConverted = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int amount);

        if (isAmountConverted)
        {
            transaction.Amount = amount;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Method: ");
        transaction.Method = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Description: ");
        transaction.Description = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Recurring: ");
        transaction.Recurring = Console.ReadLine();

        DBAccess.AddTransaction(transaction);
    }
}
```

This is the database:

[image: This is the database]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Transaction` is a [**Keyword**](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-transaction/). you should replace `Transaction` to `[Transaction]` in your query

```
public static void AddTransaction(Transaction transaction)
{
    using IDbConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnection());
    dbConnection.Execute("INSERT INTO [Transaction] (Category, Name, Type, Date, Amount, Method, Description, Recurring" +
            ") VALUES (@Category, @Name, @Type, @Date, @Amount, @Method, @Description, @Recurring)", transaction);
}
```

Comment: Farhad Zamani thanks dude you’ve corrected, I was pulling my hair out trying to deal with this.

Comment: @David Glad i helped you ;). if my answer is correct please accept my answer as correct answer.

Comment: @FarhadZamani thanks for your solution, i had same problem but with a field so also you we can do "INSERT INTO Action ([Order], Name) ...."